# JavaFX Textfield with listener gives: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end"

Tags: java, regex, exception, listener, textfield

i am getting an exception and don't understand what causes it. It's an FX App with FXML files. At the init() part of the App i add a listener to a textfield which calls a function that monitors the String with a regex for a pattern.

```
tf.textProperty().addListener(
        (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            handleInput(newValue);
        });
```

the function:

```
private void handleInput(String s) {

            s = s.toUpperCase();
            Matcher matcher = Pattern
                    .compile(
                            "^[A-Z]{2}(20|21|22|23|[0-1]\\d)[0-5]\\d(20|21|22|23|[0-1]\\d)[0-5]\\d(T\\s|C\\s|TC|CT|\\s\\s)$")
                    .matcher(s);

            if (matcher.find()) {

                    // do something

                    // then clear the textfield
                    tf.clear();

                } else {
                    // do something else
                }
            }
```

It works but gives me an exception in case the matcher matches.

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.getText(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.updateContent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin.replaceText(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.replaceText(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.defaultKeyTyped(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$75(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$$Lambda$88/1978656397.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$349(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$349/1135388943.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)}
```

i already tried some suggestions which i found here in other posts, like to check the String before giving it to the matcher:

```
if (!tf.getText() == null) {
```

or

```
if (!tf.getText().equals("") {
```

but the exception remains. When i remove:

```
tf.clear();
```

everything works fine.

... any ideas anyone?

**EDIT to swinkler's solution:**

the exception with sources i get when using swinkler's code - JDK 1.8.0_45:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.getText(TextInputControl.java:446)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.updateContent(TextInputControl.java:564)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin.replaceText(TextFieldSkin.java:576)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.replaceText(TextFieldBehavior.java:202)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.defaultKeyTyped(TextInputControlBehavior.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:139)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$75(BehaviorBase.java:135)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$$Lambda$91/476337053.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3965)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3911)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2502)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:147)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$349(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$142/181559839.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:227)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:956)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Seems like you are adding a listener for when the textProperty() of the text field changes. If you want to change what the text should have while handling the event, you should do it with the `new value` parameter instead of using `clear()`

Comment: I like to have the textfield ready for a new input once the string has matched the pattern. I also tried to use tf.settext("") instead of tf.clear(). It also gives the same exception.

Comment: The point is, you shouldn't try to modify the text in the field because you are in the middle of handling the `text modified` event. I think the correct way is setting the parametter `newValue` to "".

Comment: Ok, thanks, i got your idea. But I don't know how to do it properly. When I set the newValue in the listener part to "" it doesn't clear the textfield. When i set the String s in the called function to "" it doesn't have any effect. My intention is to get the value from the textfield without useing a button or extra key when the value matches. Maybe you have any other idea how to handle it?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526702/javafx-textarea-with-listener-gives-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-the-st) and found the bug report [JDK-8081700](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081700), which solved the problem. It turns out not a bug.

> The test case attempts to modify the text property inside the change
>   handler. This is not supported, and the property event handlers are
>   not re-entrant.
>
> The correct way is for the application to delay the modification,
>   using runLater():
>
> ```
>     if (matcher.find()) { 
>         System.err.println("true"); 
>         Platform.runLater(() -> { 
>             textField.clear(); 
>         }); 
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get your error when using this in a simple JavaFX application. Here is the code I used to test your implementation. My test input is "AA20552055T " to match the regexp - the textfield gets cleared.

Can you please compare with your solution:

```
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The Controller class with your logic:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField textfield;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        textfield.textProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    handleInput(newValue);
                });
    }

    private void handleInput(String s) {

        s = s.toUpperCase();
        Matcher matcher = Pattern
                .compile(
                        "^[A-Z]{2}(20|21|22|23|[0-1]\\d)[0-5]\\d(20|21|22|23|[0-1]\\d)[0-5]\\d(T\\s|C\\s|TC|CT|\\s\\s)$")
                .matcher(s);

        if (matcher.find()) {

                    // do something
                    // then clear the textfield
            textfield.clear();

        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

The FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication1.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <TextField layoutX="126" layoutY="150"  fx:id="textfield" /> 
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Regarding the comment, I installed JDK 1.8.0_45 (before 1.8.0_20)
Working on Windows 7 x64
Again, no error.

[Here is the jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2vtdZkiYM7OamlwRTZGZ3ZSTzA/view?usp=sharing) Netbeans creates automatically - I tested it from CMD. Works also fine. Can you test if the jar file executed from CMD is working fine on your machine?

For debugging - this is the method where the exception data are given by the `change` parameter. change has a `start` and `end`.

```
 private void updateContent(TextFormatter.Change change, boolean forceNewUndoRecord) {
        final boolean nonEmptySelection = getSelection().getLength() > 0;
        String oldText = getText(change.start, change.end);
```

The start and end values then trigger the exception in `getText(...)`:

```
 public String getText(int start, int end) {
        if (start > end) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The start must be <= the end");
        }

        if (start < 0
            || end > getLength()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        return getContent().get(start, end);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I did a cut and paste and get the same error (this time with sources, posted below. I forgot to  implement Initializable *ooops* - time to take a break.) -  btw. i am using JDK 1.8.0_45

Comment: @VictorRomeo: I added some environment information.

Comment: thanks - i get an error with your .jar - screenshot here: http://up.picr.de/22049687bw.jpg - any ideas?

Comment: @VictorRomeo - Looks like trying to re-install the JDK.

Comment: just did it - no change ... strange ... i am on Windows 8 64Bit

Comment: Bug report submited - i will post results here