# JavaFX TextArea with listener gives: “java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end”

Tags: java, exception, javafx, textarea, listener

I am getting the exception when trying to change text in the text property listener. The exception is exactly the same is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465313/javafx-textfield-with-listener-gives-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-the-s). I used TextArea instead of TextField, but I think the source of the bug is the same. It's in the "TextInputControl.java". It seems to be Java 8's bug.

```
@FXML
private TextArea ta;
ta.setText("12-");  // pre-set text 
ta.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    ta.setText("1"); // changed text
});
```

This causes the exception on my machine. I have JDK 1.8.0_51 on Win 7 64-bit. However, this dosen't cause the exception if I switch back to JDK 1.8.0_25.

I tired a range of "pre-set text" and "changed text" combinations and I found that, generally, if it's more like to cause the exception when the length of "changed text" is short then the "pre-set text".

Is there an workaround for this issue? Or did I make mistakes somewhere?

Thanks for the help.

**Edit**:
The following code will reproduce the issue. I tested with jre 8u60, and the issue still exists.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            TextArea ta =  new TextArea();
            ta.setText("12-");  // pre-set text 
            ta.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                ta.setText("1"); // changed text
            });
            AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
            root.getChildren().addAll(ta);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

After creating the window, the TextArea will show "12-". By trying to insert a character anywhere, the TextArea will change to "1" but with the following exception produced:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.getText(TextInputControl.java:446)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.updateContent(TextInputControl.java:564)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextAreaBehavior.replaceText(TextAreaBehavior.java:305)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.defaultKeyTyped(TextInputControlBehavior.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:139)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextAreaBehavior.callAction(TextAreaBehavior.java:259)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:147)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:227)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Clearing before changing text doesn't help either because even just clearing the text, ie. ta.clear();, would cause the same exception. Any ideas? Is there a JIRA ticket about this already?

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like a bug. Wouldnt be the first time something like this happens from one version to the other. Most of the time I have a look at the [JavaFX Jira](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) and see if there are any open issues. I didnt find it at this point. As a workaround I would suggest to use another component, probably the `Label` instead of the `TextArea` if you only want to display text.

Edit:

Have a look at:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081700

Comment: Thanks for the Jira information. Can I input text using Label?

Comment: What do you want to do actually? The label would only be possible as an alternative if you only want to display text. You cant use the label to enter text. In your example you have got a listener on the textarea, but what is the idea. What do you want to do as soon as the user changed the text?

Comment: I cant test it at the moment, but did you ever try to use a clear and then appendText(String text) instead of setText to change the text in the textarea? Probably that would work.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It might work. What I want to do is to format user inputted text on the fly. For example, "112233AABBCC" would become "11-22-33-AA-BB-CC-". The code works doesn't cause the exception in JDK 1.8.0_25 but the caret doesn't get set correctly. JDK 1.8.0_51 fixed the caret bug but creates the exception.

Comment: I would try what happens if you clear the text before you change it.

Comment: I tried with .clear() method but the method itself causes the same exception too. How do I search if there is a ticket at the JIRA for issue already? Thanks.

Comment: The issues are not in the same jira as before, but you can found them now at https://bugs.openjdk.java.net.

Comment: Thanks!! I found the bug report [JDK-8081700](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081700), and it solved my problem.