# JavaFX Spinner throwing IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I am using spinners in my `JavaFX` application. I have added below `listener` to my spinner to always get the updated value from the `Spinner`. This `Spinner` is double value spinner.

```
 lengthOverAllSpinner.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            try {
                lengthOverAllSpinner.getValueFactory().setValue(Double.parseDouble(newValue));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                lengthOverAllSpinner.getValueFactory().setValue(Double.parseDouble(oldValue));
            }
        });
```

But when I try to edit my spinner from GUI (E.g. current value is 340.23) and when I press backspace and remove the value till decimal place below exception is thrown but I get the updated value always. No idea why this exception is coming. Kindly help:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end
at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.getText(TextInputControl.java:446)
at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.updateContent(TextInputControl.java:564)
at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:548)
at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.deleteText(TextInputControl.java:496)
at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.deletePreviousChar(TextInputControl.java:897)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin.deleteChar(TextFieldSkin.java:589)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.deleteChar(TextFieldBehavior.java:198)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.deletePreviousChar(TextInputControlBehavior.java:311)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:143)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$75(BehaviorBase.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$$Lambda$206/1978625466.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3965)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3911)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2502)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:147)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$349(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$459/610595104.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:227)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:956)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2058534881.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem relates to this isse: [JavaFX Textfield with listener gives: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465313/javafx-textfield-with-listener-gives-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-the-s)

I don't think that it is a good idea to set the `Spinner` value in the editor `TextField` of your `Spinner`.

From the documentation of [editableProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html#editableProperty) of `Spinner`:

> If editable is true, user input will be received once the user types
>   and presses the Enter key. At this point the input is passed to the
>   SpinnerValueFactory converter StringConverter.fromString(String)
>   method. The returned value from this call (of type T) is then sent to
>   the SpinnerValueFactory.setValue(Object) method. If the value is
>   valid, it will remain as the value. If it is invalid, the value
>   factory will need to react accordingly and back out this change.

So, the default working is that you are only editiong the text until you press Enter key. On Enter key press the text of the `TextField` is commited, and passed to the `fromString` method of the [valueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html#valueFactoryProperty) of your `Spinner`. You could handle this case in the factory like:

```
lengthOverAllSpinner.getValueFactory().setConverter(new StringConverter<Double>() {
    private final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");

    @Override public String toString(Double value) {
        // If the specified value is null, return a zero-length String
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }

        return df.format(value);
    }

    @Override public Double fromString(String value) {
        try {
            // If the specified value is null or zero-length, return null
            if (value == null) 
                return null;

            value = value.trim();

            if (value.length() < 1) 
                return null; 

            // Perform the requested parsing  
            return df.parse(value).doubleValue();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
});
```

Additionally you can filter the inputs to do not accept illegal characters by using a [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) on the `TextField`:

```
TextFormatter<Object> textFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(c -> {

    if (c.getText().matches("[^0-9.,]+") && !c.getText().isEmpty())
        return null;

    SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory factory = (SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory) spinner.getValueFactory();
    try {
        Double newVal = Double.parseDouble(c.getControlNewText());
        return (newVal >= factory.getMin() && factory.getMax() >= newVal) ? c : null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        c.setText("0.0");
        return c;
    }
});

spinner.getEditor().setTextFormatter(textFormatter);
```

This formatter will only accept numbers and "." and "," characters.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I added a call at the end of `fromString` to set the text based on the result from the method instead of adding a `textFormatter` to the editor though, works well too!