# JavaFX TextFormatter issue with null text

Tags: java, javafx

I encounter problem with JavaFX textformatter. I was wondering if I am doing something wrong or there is bug in Java JDK.

Here is code that shows problem:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField field = new TextField("test0");
        field.setTextFormatter(new TestTextFormatter());
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Test");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            field.setText(null);
            field.setText("test");
        });
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(btn);
        root.setCenter(field);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    class TestTextFormatter extends TextFormatter<String> {
        public TestTextFormatter() {
            super(c -> {
                System.out.println("newControlText=" + c.getControlNewText());
                return c;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

click the button few times.
First time works as expected
Output is:
newControlText=test0
newControlText=
newControlText=test

Second and every next attempt causes exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.getText(TextInputControl.java:446)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextInputControlFromatterAccessor.getText(TextInputControl.java:1609)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter$Change.getControlNewText(TextFormatter.java:453)
    at TestApp$TestTextFormatter.lambda$0(TestApp.java:34)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.filterAndSet(TextInputControl.java:1165)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.access$900(TextInputControl.java:79)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.doSet(TextInputControl.java:1410)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.set(TextInputControl.java:1323)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.setText(TextInputControl.java:349)
    at TestApp.lambda$0(TestApp.java:21)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
...
```

Could you please help me to understand where is problem (my code or JDK)?

Answer (score 2):

Please look on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32893573/814304

You are trying to change text inside event, that is exactly you not suppose to do.

Comment: That answer issue refers to changing the text value of a text field within a text property change listener, which is not what the sample code in the question is trying to do, at least not directly.  Though you are correct that that is what happens in the stack trace, so the issue would seem to be in the JavaFX library code rather than the posted code.  Perhaps something for: http://bugreport.java.com

Comment: I change text in textfield on button action EventHandler. I am allowed to do so right?
A kind of workaround is to set empty string "" instead of null - then I can click button as many times I want without Exception.
Also I did report it to oracle.

Answer (score 1):

It's a filter which throws an Exception when apply a method `c.getControlNewText()`.

If your code allows to set null values then you should rewrite the `TestTextFormatter` class as follows

```
class TestTextFormatter extends TextFormatter<String> {
    public TestTextFormatter() {
        super(c -> {
            if ( ((TextField)c.getControl()).getText() == null ) {
                return c;
            }
            System.out.println("newControlText=" + c.getControlNewText());
            return c;
        });
    }
}
```