# Regex : Digits followed by only one character

Tags: java, regex, javafx

I'm trying to create a regex that will allow only digits followed by only one character after every digit within a Textfield

Regex that needs to match - \d*\+{1}

Regex in case it does not match - [^\d*\+){1}] will replace with "" (removes everything else)

```
final String regexFinalInteger = "\\d*\\+{1}";

    numberElements.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValueE, newValueE) -> {
        if (!newValueE.matches(regexFinalInteger)) {
            numberElements.setText(newValueE.replaceAll("[^\\d*\\+){1}]", ""));
        }
    });
```

I will expect an output of 122+1+3 but the actual output can be 1++2+++4+123 (multiple +)

Comment: Try `.replaceAll("(\\d+\\+)|.", "$1")`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KFqKDj/1).

Comment: Are you trying to remove all non-digit chars that follow digits, except the first non-digit char? Could you please provide some sample input and expected output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - tried to implement the Regex. Modified the **final String regexFinalInteger** to **\\d*\\+** and the replaceAll as you stated. Apparently, everything I try to write gets deleted automatically along with a Trow ex _java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end_. **Bohemian**- I'm trying to create a Textfield which allows only inputs like **number/digits+number/digit+....**. Only 1 "+" between the number/digit ( 92+1+23 and **not** 432++31+1+++3

Comment: @VladMurea That is not related to the regex, but how the code handles the regex replacement result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465313/javafx-textfield-with-listener-gives-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-the-s, it is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to replace multiple `+`s with only one.

I believe this would enable what you're looking for:

```java
String regex = "[+](?=[+])";

String text = "122+1+3";
assertEquals("122+1+3", text.replaceAll(regex, ""));

text = "1++2+++4+123";
assertEquals("1+2+4+123", text.replaceAll(regex, ""));
```

That is my first Java program, I'm sorry if it offends someone.